# PDF display in Android using WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to display PDF in Android using `WebView`, I'm using `google docs` for this purpose. It was working fine till this morning. But all of a sudden it's throwing `502` error.
Is there any alternative to display PDF's in `WebView`.

This is the URL I have been using to render PDF in `WebView`

`https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=`+URL

It looks like `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=` is down.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way**

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        if (url.endsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            // Load "url" in google docs

           String googleDocs = "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="; 
           mWebView.loadUrl(googleDocs + url);

        }
        else
        {
            // Load all other urls normally.
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
     }
```

**UPDATE try this**

```
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
```

Comment: even if I access the URL through browser it's throwing same error, so this is not issue from app :(.

Comment: webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdf); try this

Comment: it's throwing the same error...issue is that the google docs URL is throwing that error, not the app. So I was wondering if there is any other alternative to display PDF in WebView

Comment: are you running on device or emulator?

Comment: device...even if I access URL through my laptop, its throwing the same